# Permission for new folders on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, permissions

when I create a new folder named "child" (for example) like this:

```
parent/child/
```

the child folder, doesn't have the same permission of the parent! I already changed them, to the parent, using `chmod -R +rw parent` but each new folder created doesn't get the same values!! I want +rw for 'everyone' on that new folder.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are no inheritance mechanism, but you can use umask for your case.

Example of how it works:

```
$ umask
022
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ mkdir 1
$ ls -la 1
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 receiver  wheel   68 23 May 16:57 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 receiver  wheel  136 23 May 16:57 ..
```

Above we have 022 masked out. Let's set umask to 000:

```
$ umask 000
$ mkdir 2
$ ls -la 2
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  2 receiver  wheel   68 23 May 16:58 .
drwxrwxrwx  5 receiver  wheel  170 23 May 16:58 ..
```